# Как написать условие в регулярном выражении?

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Есть несколько ссылок:
- https://example.com/image/logo.png
- https://yandex.ru/image/logo.png
- https://google.com/image/logo.png

Нужно написать условие которое будет находить расширение картинки **.png** только в домене **example.com**

Это делается для того, что бы в будущем вставить это регулярное выражение в код который будет заменять .png на .webp только в домене example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно так:

```
//example\.com/[^"\s]*\.png
```

Заменять можно `(//example\.com/[^"\s]*\.)png` на `$1webp`.

Comment: проверяю через сайт https://regex101.com - и получаю ошибку "Your pattern contains one or more errors, please see the explanation section above."

Comment: @ВладимирВ., потому что он хочет регулярку в js-синтаксисе, итак что надо экранировать слеши. Поскольку в вопросе ты язык не указывал, я написал просто текст регулярки без избыточного экранирования. https://i.stack.imgur.com/drfKk.png

Comment: Здесь оно выбирает полностью всю строку, а мне нужно, что бы выбирало лишь .png (при условии, что в строке есть example.com)

Comment: @ВладимирВ., не нужно. Заключи левую часть в скобки и заменяй на `$1webp`.

Comment: Благодарю вас! Для меня было открытие, что можно сделать через $1

Answer (score 0):

Если движок регулярных выражений позволяет, то можно так:

```
(?<=//example\.com/[^"\s]*\.)png
```